# No me cargan mi carpeta de imagenes fuentes y audios

Tags: html, css, rutas

Estuve realizando una web sencilla básica, todo iba bien hasta que después de un buen rato todo se bugeo primero las animaciones y el javascript luego las fuentes y los estilos se fue arreglando solo no modifique mucho solo cerré y volví a abrir es raro de echo, pero ahora no se soluciona aparentemente he visto que únicamente los templates osea mi carpeta de fotos audios y fuentes no me carga eh intentado ponerle a las rutas con "/" y con "./" como por ahí leí pero aun así no funciona, sobre las rutas de las imágenes también le agregue "/" y "./" verifique que sea correcto pero no me carga ni una imagen o fuente, mas los estilos y animaciones si me cargan normal así como el javascript.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor, coloca tu código HTML, CSS y Javascript para resolver tu problema particular de una forma eficaz.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me deja subir mas imagenes ese es mi html y en mi css pongo las imagenes como fondo de backgroundImage